# MySQL 5.5. Error when create trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I try to create trigger in mysql 5.5 to prevent insert empty string in not null fields:

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_empty_fields
    BEFORE INSERT ON customer_address
        FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
        IF new.customer_name = '' THEN SET new.customer_name = NULL ;
END IF;

        IF new.customer_address = '' THEN SET new.customer_address = NULL ;
END IF;

END;
```

But i get this error:

```
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5
```

Comment: This situation might be better handled in your UI validation or in the business layer rather than the persistence layer.

Comment: why check the data *after* it has been saved?

Comment: `customer_address` is both a table and a field name, right?

Comment: Yes. Custommer address is both a table and a field name